# day & month parameters unfilled? (datetime)

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to figure out how to return the difference of time in between now and from the last minute of this year. I seem to be getting errors saying "Parameter 'day' unfilled" and "Parameter 'month' unfilled".

```
 from datetime import datetime
        rn = datetime.now()
        ny = datetime('2022, 12, 31, 23, 59')
        df = ny - rn
        print(df.total_seconds())
```

if anyone could help out with this that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You used a single string as parameter, you'd have to either use `strptime` to parse the string, or otherwise get your actual numbers out of the string

```
datetime(2022, 12, 31, 23, 59)
datetime.strptime('2022, 12, 31, 23, 59', "%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M")
```